# Python script for if/elif condition in field calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, python-parser

[image]

I need some help in calculating the last column (OD_pairs.Ai_) based on the condition; 
if travel_cost has a value below 10, OD-pairs.Ai_ takes the value of the first column(Aij_OjFCij..)
if travel_cost has a value above 10, then return 0 in OD_pairs.Ai.
So basically the third field to be calculated is either the corresponding value in the first field or zero, depending on the value in second field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is in Python, don't forget to switch to Python Parser in the Field Calculator window.

You asked for:

Pre-Logic Script Code:

```
def calcColumn(cost, Aji):
  if cost < 10:
    return Aji
  elif cost > 10: 
    return 0
```

OD_pairs.Ai_ =

```
calcColumn(!Travel_Cost!, !Aij_OjFCij_Income4!)
```

Bare in mind if you have cost = 10, it won't work, as it only handles larger than or smaller than 10. You can also instead use:

Pre-Logic Script Code:

```
def calcColumn(cost, Aji):
  if cost < 10:
    return Aji
  else:
    return 0
```

Comment: Edit: Reread his post.  It is confusing, but the code you proposed is correct.

Comment: Alvin if it works please mark as answered.